# About SEC("tp_btf/")

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf

First, tp_btf is tracepoint? tp_btf/ only followed by tracepoint such as block_rq_complete.

```
SEC("tp_btf/block_rq_complete")
int BPF_PROG(block_rq_complete, struct request *rq, int error,unsigned int nr_bytes)
```

Second, ts_btf type can get tracepoint TO_PROTO(*) params, What should I do that I can get TO_PROTO(*) params using SEC("tp/block/block_rq_complete")? or else. because I can't use tf_btf.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you looking for a way to get the list of all functions you can trace with kprobes in Linux?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.